# How to print the total count of elements in a file using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, count

I have a text file with the name of many products separated by comma (','). I want to save to a file the total count of products present in this file. How to do this using pyspark?

I've tried so far the following code, it seems that the count I get is not correct.

```
import pyspark
import random
if not 'sc' in globals():
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext()


text_file = sc.textFile("anytext.txt")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(",")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word)) 
       



counts.count()
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using it as below -

**Initial data -**

```
df = spark.read.text("/FileStore/word_count/citrus_fruit.txt")
df.show(5, False)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups             |
|tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee                                       |
|whole milk                                                         |
|pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads                        |
|other vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now counting words in each line -

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('count', F.size(F.split('value', ',')))
df2.show(5, False)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|value                                                              |count|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups             |4    |
|tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee                                       |3    |
|whole milk                                                         |1    |
|pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads                        |4    |
|other vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product|4    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Once you have the count, you just have to sum it all up as below -

```
df3 = df2.groupBy().agg(F.sum('count').alias('word_count_sum')).show(5,False)

df3.show()
+--------------+
|word_count_sum|
+--------------+
|43368         |
+--------------+
```

Now you could write this dataframe to a file as below (I've used csv here)-

```
df3.write.format('csv').mode('overwrite').save('/FileStore/tmp/')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the total count of elements in my file, not the count of unique elements

Comment: Could you share the input data along with the expected output in the question stem? Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: input is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AO2aDbTP4D0g0j5tBz2z_rQ3kcT0e0NA/view?usp=sharing  The expected output should be: Counts: XXXX where XXXX is the total counts of products in the file.

Comment: How do you intend to identify the products in the file you shared?

Comment: I need to write out the total count of products to a text file. The contents of this file should look like this:  Count:
<XXX>

Comment: Okay. So if I understood your requirement correctly, you want to count all the words that are part of that text file you shared. For example, if there are 100 words then my count should return 100. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then I need to write the total count to a file.

Comment: Thanks! it helped a lot, but I need to know how to save this count to a .txt file and add the word "count" such as: Count: 43368

Comment: I have added writing it to a csv. You could use similar approach for text file as well.

Comment: Very good! many thanks!